How to delete resources for ImageRestyle?
I am using Mathematica 14.0.
One day, suddenly running ImageRestyle causes an error.

I want to delete and re-run the resources for ImageRestyle installed on my PC. Which folder should I delete which files to erase the resources?
How to delete resources for ImageRestyle?
